# invalid Prisma.create() invocation

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma, prisma2

im trying to make a web app where I can create projects and inside those projects add requirements. Im good on the creating projects part but im having issues creating requirements for each project, maybe you guys can give a hand with this..

This is how my schema.prisma looks like

```
model Project {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  title        String         @db.VarChar(255)
  requirements Requirement[]
}

model Requirement {
  id        Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  content   String
  notes     Note[]
  estimates Estimate[]
  projectId Int
  project   Project     @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
}

model Note {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  content        String
  createdAt      DateTime      @default(now())
  requirement   Requirement? @relation(fields: [requirementId], references: [id])
  requirementId Int?
}

model Estimate {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  content        String
  createdAt      DateTime      @default(now())
  requirement   Requirement? @relation(fields: [requirementId], references: [id])
  requirementId Int?
}
```

and here is the code where I create a requirement for a project

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async (req, res) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(req.body)
    console.log(data)
    const createdRequirement = await prisma.requirement.create({
        data: {
            content: data.content,
            project: {
                connect: {
                    id: data.projectId,
                }
            }
        }
    })
    res.json(createdRequirement)
}
```

so when i try to create a requirement and i only type 'req' is the content field, this is the error i get in the terminal

```
{ content: 'req' }
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
error - Error: 
Invalid `prisma.requirement.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    content: 'req',
    project: {
      connect: {
?       id?: Int
      },
?     create?: ProjectCreateWithoutRequirementsInput | ProjectUncheckedCreateWithoutRequirementsInput,
?     connectOrCreate?: {
?       where: ProjectWhereUniqueInput,
?       create: ProjectCreateWithoutRequirementsInput | ProjectUncheckedCreateWithoutRequirementsInput
?     }
    }
  }
}

Argument data.project.connect of type ProjectWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.

Note: Lines with ? are optional.
```

So yeah, i dont know what im missing or if my schema doesnt make sense, I would appreciate some help...thank you!!

Comment: From your console output, I can see that the `data` object is `{ content: 'req' }`. Inside your Prisma query, you are trying to access `data.projectId` which will return `undefined`. The error is complaining that you did not provide a valid argument inside the `connect` option (`undefined` is ignored by Prisma). 

This is most likely the issue.